# Joining/Appending Multiple Many-to-Many Subqueries of Same Result Type

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have multiple many to many relationships all related to a single `User` class and I want to extract distinct `Users` across some set criteria, over many tables..

Here a `User` can be a member of multiple `Clubs` or `Restaurants` and each `Club` or `Restaurant` can have many `Users` who might be the same...

```
club_user_table = Table('club_user_ass', db.Model.metadata,
    Column('club_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('club.id')),
    Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)

rest_user_table = Table('rest_user_ass', db.Model.metadata,
    Column('rest_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('restaurant.id')),
    Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)

class User(db.model):
    ...
    clubs = db.relationship('Club', back_populates='club_card_holders', secondary=club_user_table)
    restaurants = db.relationship('Restaurant', back_populates='rest_card_holders', secondary=rest_user_table)

class Club(db.model):
    ...
    club_card_holders = db.relationship('User', back_populates='clubs', secondary=club_user_table)

class Restaurant(db.model):
    ...
    rest_card_holders = db.relationship('User', back_populates='restaurants', secondary=rest_user_table)
```

Suppose I would like a list of users if the club or restaurant name is "FooBar", then I can do two separate queries:

```
L1 = User.query.join(Club.club_card_holders).filter(Club.name == "FooBar").all()
L2 = User.query.join(Restaurant.rest_card_holders).filter(Restaurant.name == "FooBar").all()
```

So `L1` and `L2` are lists of users, but what I really want is the distinct (non-repeated elements) union of L1 and L2 in a pure sqlalchemy format.

Do I need to use subqueries or can this be done with another join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly simple solution:

```
L1 = User.query.join(Club.club_card_holders).filter(Club.name == "FooBar")
L2 = User.query.join(Restaurant.rest_card_holders).filter(Restaurant.name == "FooBar")

L3 = L1.union(L2)
```